# Why do I sometimes see questions in the low quality review queue that I already flagged?

Tags: support, reviews

Sometimes I flag questions because I don't think they are a good fit for the site and these questions are later shown in my low-quality review queue. Why is that the case? I already flagged them and normally they should not be visible for me, as I basically already *handled* this entry.

When I click on the "Close" button in the review queue it even shows me that I already flagged the question and I can't really do anything. Sometimes it's useful because it remindes me of questions I flagged and where I forgot or didnt't have the time to comment. But is that the reason why these questions are sometimes shown in my low-quality review queue where I only get the chance to skip or say that the quesiton is okay when I can't recommend closure?

[image: Screenshot of info box for "Close" button that shows I already flagged this question]

---

Today I had this behaviour again on [this review](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/38210), though I forgot to make a screenshot. The situation was the same as above: I flagged a question, upvoted an existing comment, but didn't yet write a comment myself. Later I saw the question in my *low-quality review queue* and wasn't able to recommend closure, as I had already flagged it. I left a comment and then had to use the skip button.

Comment: The question has been flagtedt as off topic and for low quality and thus can appear multiple times in different review queues.

Comment: @Vincent That sounds like the behaviour I see with First Posts and Late Answers. But normally when I do something on such a post, either in the review queue or outside the queue, it disappears for me from all of those queues without having to check all of them. In this case the question is suddenly back even if I don' t have all tools available that I should have because I already handled the post. It's especially confusing because I don't have the reputation to VTC

Comment: Partially related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153406/274942.